# Is query widget available in ArcGIS javascript API?

Tags: angular, widget, arcgis, feature-selection, arcgis-js-api

I want to allow users to find features based on a query expression. So I want to add a query widget to my project like in the web app builder. Is the query widget available in ArcGIS javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a standard widget available using the ArcGIS javascript API, this functionality needs to be built specifically to your app such as:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/query/